# Gives Exception (throws) when tries to insert data to SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

When I tries to insert data to sqlite in window store app it gives unexpected exception in SQLite.cs file. My code looks like:-

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Fav.db"));
favorities addData = new favorities();
addData.Name = Title.Text;
addData.desciption = desciption.Text;
con.Insert(addData);`
```

and when I click on button on which these operation are being performed run time exception arises which looks like:-[image]

in fact this SQLite.cs file is an API which I downloaded from "Manage Nuget Package" please help me out.
**Thanks & Regards,**

Comment: Could do with seeing more details from the exception.

Comment: Does the database actually exist? and if it does, does the `favorities` table exist? - I'd check these first without being able to see the whole error.

Comment: Your problem is stated in the dialog: *no such table: favorites*. You can't insert rows in a table that you didn't create in the database you're connecting to.

Comment: @rene your eyesight is better than mine... lol

Comment: I'm used to blurry pictures @Rick

Comment: Thanks All for helping :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table doesn't exist in the database.

Use this after you create the extension:

```
con.CreateTable<favorities>();
```

The creation of the connection would be better in a `using` statement too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out and saving my time :)